# Dependency to use PLUS.API in android activity

Tags: android, gradle, google-signin

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, onConnectionFailedListener)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .build();
```

What am I missing? I am not able to figure out what dependency I should add.
Please help.
AndroidStudio is not able to resolve PLUS.API Here is my gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.co.palup.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),       'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9'

    compile "palup:common:0.1"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
}
```

What am I missing? I am not able to figure out what dependency I should use.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't you be missing from your gradle dependencies

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup